# Why is a variable considered local in a nested lambda when using ":="?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does python3.8+ considers result as local variable in nested lambdas when using := but not otherwise?

```
>>> counter = (lambda result: (lambda: (result + 1)))(0)
>>> counter()
1
>>> counter = (lambda result: (lambda: (result := result + 1)))(0)
>>> counter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: A question title should be specific enough that someone looking at it in search results has a pretty good idea what the "this" you're asking about is. (I've tried to edit towards that end).

Comment: Same as with any non-lambda function. If you wrote this out with `def`, you'd get the same result.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips on how to write a good title.

Comment: BTW, [named lambdas are bad practice](/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Comment: Agreeing with @wjandrea here. If you're trying to use this code in production (and not just as an academic example), you should *really* rewrite this with [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: @Antimon Actually, I'd say don't reinvent the wheel, use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) instead. (At least, I assume that's what OP's trying to do.) I assumed the code in the question is just an example.

Comment: Very good point! But in general, if you start writing nested lambdas, step away from the keyboard and ask yourself what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scoping rules for variables created by `:=` are the same as they are for `=` (as long as a comprehension is not involved). `result := result + 1` creates a new local variable named `result` that shadows the parameter of the outer function. As `result` is not defined before the assignment expression, trying to evaluate `result + 1` produces a `NameError`.

As you cannot use a `nonlocal` statement in a lambda expression, there is no way to update the value of the outer function's `result` variable using a plain assignment. (While you could hack something together with the `exec` function, I recommend against it and will not show an example of how to do so here.)